# How to develop microservice architecture in nodejs

Tags: node.js, docker, express, kubernetes, microservices

How can I build microservice architecture using nodejs express any guide or reference thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a microservices architecture, we build services which are loosely coupled. So in node js you have to create loosely coupled services which can interact with each other to serve your application data. For small size application, you can have like 10-100 services. After you have a few services, you can containerize then for making them more isolated. Docker and k8s will help in putting services in containers and maintaining them automatically.

Comment: how can a service interact with each other and there is any tutorial of making a micro service architecture in nodejs

Comment: you can use `nodeport` or ingress in k8s to interact between services or externally